# How to suggest a similar question

Tags: support, questions, duplicate, closed-questions

How to suggest a similar question when we find a possible duplicate, or when it is answered in another thread, as show in the following dialog?

[image: Similar question suggested dialog]

Is there a privilege associated with this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a privilege, called [**flagging**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), granted in this site at 15 rep. You flag a post as a *duplicate* if you feel it has been already answered.

> ### Flag posts
>
> Privilege type: Moderation privilege
>   Awarded at: 15 reputation
>
> #### What is flagging?
>
> Flagging is a way of bringing inappropriate content to the attention
>   of the community. The currently implemented flag types are the
>   following:
>
> [...]
>
> 4. Flag to close (questions only)
>
>    1. Duplicate question

You need one more upvote to get this privilege.